# Can't get android 1.6 to open an email with the recipient's email address already in it

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to get Android 1.6 to compose an email with the recipient's email saved as a string (not in the res/values/string.xml file, because the string won't be constant). Nothing I tried so far has worked. My code is

```
public void SendMail(final String sender)
{
Intent emailIntent2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{sender});
emailIntent2.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent2, "Send mail client :"));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it hasn't worked? What happens? And I would change "text/plain" to "message/rfc822" as the other can open more than just email applications

Comment: It just opens a blank email with no one as the recipient

Comment: Are you sure "sender" isn't null? Have you tried hardcoding a String into it to test? IE. emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "example@somedomain.com" });

Comment: I'm positive it is not null but I checked with a phoney email and it still didn't work, I'll try changing it from text/plain

Comment: Now I got no applications can perform this action.

Comment: Well the code you posted above is definitely correct... Could it have something to do with such an early Android version?

Comment: Maybe, if it's correct I can't think of any other reason it wouldn't work.